# Kafka string serialization efficiency

Tags: java, serialization, encoding, apache-kafka

I am new to Kafka and am trying to store messages with the least memory overhead, so want to avoid field names in my encoding (ie. JSON).  Consider a message with three *variable length* `String` fields,

```
Interface IMessage:
   String getA()
   String getB()
   String getC()
```

Since Kafka includes a default [String Serializer](https://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/StringSerializer.html), the easiest way to encode would be to simply concatenate and delimit the fields. Something like,

```
String encoded = "FieldA|FieldB|FieldC"
```

Under the hood, Kafka will convert this to a byte array.

My question is, will kafka use Java's default UTF-8 encoding such that each ASCII character in my string only take up one byte?  In other words, will a 15 character string take up 15 bytes in Kafka's memory?  Or is it more efficient for some reason to call `toBytes()` in Java and pass the bytearray directly into [ByteArraySerializer](https://kafka.apache.org/082/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/ByteArraySerializer.html)?

```
byte[] encoded = "FieldA|FieldB|FieldC".toBytes()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Documentation for this class states

> String encoding defaults to UTF8 and can be customized by setting the property key.serializer.encoding, value.serializer.encoding or serializer.encoding. The first two take precedence over the last.

So, default encoding is UTF-8 as you need it.

Also, you can download sources and find:

```
private String encoding = "UTF8";

@Override
public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
    String propertyName = isKey ? "key.serializer.encoding" : "value.serializer.encoding";
    Object encodingValue = configs.get(propertyName);
    if (encodingValue == null)
        encodingValue = configs.get("serializer.encoding");
    if (encodingValue != null && encodingValue instanceof String)
        encoding = (String) encodingValue;
}
```

So, sources match documentation, which is good.

If you want to be sure you can define `key.serializer.encoding` and `value.serializer.encoding` to be `UTF8`

Comment: Thanks, appreciate it